# Combining two bytes in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem where I get two bytes represented as an int from 0-255, two bytes are supposed to represent one value. Right now I am doing it like this, but it takes way to a long time. Any tips?

```
bin_string = '0b' + bin(int(second_byte))[2:].zfill(8) + bin(int(first_byte))[2:].zfill(8)
result = float(literal_eval(bin_string))

example: 
203 -> 11001011
101 -> 01100101
-> 1100101101100101 -> 52069
```

I feel like there could be a simple mathematical formula but I cannot seem to figure it out ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you combine two bytes in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168123/how-do-you-combine-two-bytes-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left-shift the second byte by 8 bits and bitwise OR it with the first byte:

```
(second_byte << 8) | first_byte
```

For extra safety clamp both bytes to `[0, 255]` with a bitwise AND:

```
((second_byte & 0xFF) << 8) | (first_byte & 0xFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary shift operator:

```
(second_byte << 8) + first_byte
```

Same as:

```
second_byte * 256 + first_byte
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get your bytes in a `bytes` value, i. e. a string of bytes, or if you want to put your bytes into one, then you should have a look at the `struct` module:

```
 struct.unpack('h', b'\x00\x01')
```

will return `(256,)` which is a tuple of all the unpacked stuff from the string `b'\x00\x01'` according to the format `'h'`.